# qmailとドメインの関係について

Tags: qmail

abcdefg@user.xxx.comがあったとして、qmailを使用していて、このメールアドレスにメールを飛ばした場合になぜか、/home/userというフォルダに移動する感じでした。

なぜ@userがuserに移動するのかがわかりません。

**コメントを受けて追記:**
バーチャルドメインを調べてみましたら、そのような設定がしてありました。
よくわかりましたね。

rcpthostsファイルに記述ありでした。

次に転送先に、そのユーザーへ飛べ的な記述がありました。
user.domain.com:user

今度は次にどのファイルが動くのかがわかりません。
この中に起動するファイルがあるのは記述でわかるんですけど。
.qmail-defaultっていう、キャッチオールアカウントが動くようになってるんですかね？？

次はこのファイルを見ればいいのかな？

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！ こちらの質問ですが、もう少し詳しく手順を説明していただけないでしょうか？　どういう設定をして、どういう作業をしたときに結果がどうなって、その結果のどの部分に納得されていないのかを書いていただければと思います。自分の質問には「編集」から自由に追記できますので、お願いします。

Comment: 暗黙の了解ではなくて、qmail の virtual domain が設定されているのではないでしょうか(DNS の MX レコードの設定も必要ですが)。

Comment: 誰かが意図的に設定を行ったはずなので、その誰かさんに確認すれば良いかと思いますよ。まぁでも、もしかしてその人とは連絡が取れない状況なのかもしれませんが…